# How do you create a multi button confirmation on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uikit, sdk, uialertview, uiactionsheet

On the iPhone, in the Calendar App when you press the "Delete Event" button a confirmation slides in from the bottom. Does anyone know of any example code for this, or is it just a short view presented modally with a custom background?

If this is made using a custom view, do you know where I can get a background graphic the same as the one used in the Calendar App?

Thanks in advance!

NB: I am not talking about a UIAlertView dialog box, but the slide-in confirmation with multiple buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIActionSheet is what you are looking for.

Here is some code example to get you started with:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save photo?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
 [actionSheet release];
```

This will slide in an action sheet from the bottom. It has 2 buttons. Yes and No.

When a user selects any button the `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method gets called

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
//your code here
}
```

Your controller class will have to subscribe to the < UIActionSheetDelegate > protocol

Hope this helps!

Comment: Lovely, thanks for the quick answer. Here was I thinking Action Sheets were only on the iPad!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"  destructiveButtonTitle:@"destructive" otherButtonTitles:@"other", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet release];
```